# Application does not own action type

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-opengraph

I am working with an application that uses facebook opengraph to post custom objects to a user's wall with a respective custom action. While working in an iOS environment, I am attempting to use the SDK function call:

`- (FBRequest*)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
                         andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
                     andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
                       andDelegate:(id <KC_FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;`

to post the object. I specified the GraphPath as:

```
"me/[APP_NAME]:[APP_ACTION]"
```

and supplied the Params with a correct access token, api_key, and url to the object to be posted on the user's wall.

I then receive the error message:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Application does not own 479077275455517 action type","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

in the response from Facebook.

Any insights?

Answer (score 5):

While following a [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/) for iOS SDK integration, I experienced this same issue running tests through the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), until  I finally noticed the sentence on the tutorial: "Go to the Graph API Explorer and select your app from the ''Application'' list."

Essentially I was attempting to post an action to the Graph API Explorer app itself, hence the error, since I do not have privileges to access that app, obviously.

So with that said, most likely somewhere in the setup of the Facebook sdk in your project, you have not entered or incorrectly entered your facebook app id, which produces the error you see.

Answer (score 0):

> Application does not own **479077275455517** action type

Is that the *name* of your action? I doubt it. Rather looks like it might be your app id.

That clearly points to a wrongly build Graph URL. Write it somewhere for debugging, and see what it *really* contains.

Comment: 479077275455517 is an action type ID, the error is implying that his app is trying to post those actions, but isn't the same app that created the action - i'm assuming `['APP NAME']` means the namespace, not the name itself

Comment: yeah, which is what has me stumped, I've checked my action type IDs and they are consistent, I do own that ID, but it still throws the error.

Comment: One think I would like to ask however, is it necessary for the actions to be approved for it to work? I don't think this would be an issue because I am trying to perform the action on my own account which is the same account that I created the application on. Also, I am able to post the action use CURL on the terminal, but on iOS, I don't own the action? It's bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I had this same problem and recently resolved it. Be sure to check the FB API call for the correct [APP_NAME]. In my case, I had a test app and a live app, and I had coded the live [APP_NAME] in my FB API call:

FB.api("me/[APP_NAME]:[APP_ACTION]"...

So even though I had the my test app ID in the init, I was calling the prod app namespace in my FB API call.

Yes, [APP NAME] represents the app's namespace.

Hope this helps to clarify for anyone else who runs into this issue.